# C++ linked list doesn stop growing

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I'm trying to write a function that calculates the N-th Fibonacci number using doubly linked lists, but for some reason when I compile and run the linked list does not stop growing, it keeps adding 1 number over and over with no ending.

This should be a SSCCE:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class node {
    public:
        int value;
        node* previous;
        node* next;
};//node

class number {
    public:
        node* start;
        node* end;
        node* add (int value);
        void show (int K);
        number ();
        void destroy ();

        void copy (number gg1);
        void addition (number gg1, number gg2, int K);

        void fibonacci (int K, int times);

};//number

number::number () {
    start = NULL;
    end = NULL;
}

int power (int K) {
    int L = 1;
    for (int i = (K-1); i > 0; i--) {
        L = L*10;
    }
    return L;
}

int checksize (int value) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (value != 0) {
        value = value / 10;
        counter += 1;
    }
    return counter;
}

void number::show (int K) {
    node* current;
    cout << "\nValue:" << endl;
    if (start == NULL) {
        cout << "\nNothing\n" << endl;
    }
    if (start != NULL) {
        current = start;
        while (current != NULL) {
            if (current->value == 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
                    cout << "0";
                }
            cout << "\n";
            }
            else {
                int size = checksize (current->value);
                for (int j = size; j < K; j++) {
                    cout << "0";
                }
            cout << current->value << endl;
            }
            current = current->next;
        }   
    }
    //cout << "\n";
}

int main () {
    number gg1;
    number gg2;
    number gg3;
    const int K = 5;

    gg1.fibonacci (K, 10);
}

node* number::add(int value) {   
        node* currentcode;                   
        if (start == NULL){                    
            currentcode = new node;      
            start = currentcode;               
            end = currentcode;            
            currentcode->next =  NULL;    
            currentcode->previous = NULL;    
            currentcode->value = value;
            return currentcode;
        }
        if (start != NULL) {                    
            currentcode = new node;    
            currentcode->next = NULL;   
            end->next = currentcode;  
            currentcode->previous = end;  
            end = currentcode;          
            currentcode->value = value;
            return currentcode;
        }
         return NULL;
}

void number::addition (number gg1, number gg2, int K) {
    int value1, value2, value3;
    int carry = 0;
    node* current1;
    node* current2;
    current1 = gg1.start;
    current2 = gg2.start;
    while (current1 != NULL || current2 != NULL) {
        if (current1 != NULL && current2 !=NULL) {
            value1 = current1->value;
            value2 = current2->value;
            value3 = value1 + value2 + carry;
            current1 = current1->next;
            current2 = current2->next;
        }
        else if (current1 == NULL && current2 != NULL) {
            value3 = current2->value + carry;
            current2 = current2->next;
        }
        else if (current1 != NULL && current2 == NULL) {
            value3 = current1->value + carry;
            current1 = current1->next;
        }

        checksize(value3);
        if (value3 > power(K)) {
            value3 = value3 - 10*(power(K));
            carry = 1;
        }
        else 
            carry = 0;

        add(value3);

        if ((current1 == NULL && current2 == NULL) && (carry == 1))
            add(1);
    }
}

void number::destroy () {
    node* current;
    node* current2;
    if (start != NULL) {
        current = start;
        current2 = current->next;
        while (current2 != NULL) {
            delete current;
            current = current2;
            current2 = current->next;
        }
        delete current;
    }
}   

void number::fibonacci (int K, int times) {
    number g1;
    number g2;
    number g3;
    destroy ();

    g1.add (1);
    g2.add (1);

    g3.addition (g1, g2, K);
    g2.copy(g1);

    g1.show(K);
    g2.show(K);

        //g1.copy(g3);

        //g1.show(K);
        //g2.show(K);
        //g3.show(K);

        //g3.addition (g1, g2, K);
        //g3.show(K);
        //g2.copy(g1);
        //g1.copy(g3);

    /*for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        g3.addition (g1, g2, K);
        g3.show(K);
        g2.copy(g1);
        g1.copy(g3);
    }*/

    copy(g3);
}

void number::copy (number gg1) {
    int value;
    destroy ();
    node* current = gg1.start;
    while (current != NULL) {
        value = current->value;
        add(value);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Whenever I run the Fibonacci function it gives me endless 1's in the terminal.
The *number* class is just a basic doubly linked pointer list.

The addition function standalone works just fine, so does the copy. In fact everything was working fine until this. It's easy to finish the function with a for-loop, but this error prevents me from doing so. Does anyone know what my mistake is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `delete ();` doing there, and why isn't it a compilation error?

Comment: How can you use delete function as your defined function? It must have given you error. Or you are just writting this code on the fly.Kindly provide the `addition` function.

Comment: "It keeps **adding** one number over and over again". Perhaps seeing `add()` and `addition()` may have some benefits as well?

Comment: Also I suspect your show() might be in error - so give us that one.

Comment: Well, I just roughly translated it into delete, that's not the problem. In the real program it has another name. The addition() function works fine, I don't think the problem is there either. So is the add().

Comment: For what purpose would you have to rename the function, much less rename it to something that violates the standard by using a reserved word? Regardless, please post a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org) so we can actually *see* what is failing (and thus tell you *why*).

Comment: @user1939088: Don't change the code. **Copy and Paste** your exact code. Any changes are likely to introduce other errors and uncomilable code is just going to confuse people with errors that don't exist. If you can make it so that we can compile and run the code to verify your results it will make debugging the problem a lot quicker. If you only give us part of the problem there will be a lot of guessing.

Comment: I've replaced all names with something that makes sense now.

Comment: You will have to trace step by step what happens when you run your code. A debugger will help you do this.

Comment: Well, it goes wrong at the g2.copy(g1) part. After that it just keeps adding that single node without ending..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you have invalid memory access, since calling `delete` on each node in `destroy()` does not NULL-out the memory but it only marks the memory free.

Suggested correction:

```
void number::destroy () {
    node* current;
    node* current2;
    if (start != NULL) {
        current = start;
        current2 = current->next;
        while (current2 != NULL) {
            delete current;
            current = current2;
            current2 = current->next;
        }
        delete current;
    }
    start = NULL; // so you can't access the now non-existing list anymore.
    end = NULL;
}
```

---

Remark:

- Class names should be capital-first by widely adapted convention.
- You should not pass a class by value in your copy and addition function but const-ref.
- Better use in this case `operator=` instead of `copy`. `copy` can be `copy_from` or `copy_to`, calling a function `copy` is ambigous, really.
- Always better to use for loops when you can.
- `Node` is not a class but a struct, it is better to call it a struct.

The new code can also look like this:

```
Number& Number::operator=(const Number& n)
{
  destroy();
  for(Node* current = gg1.start; current; current = current->next)
    add(current->value);
}

void Number::destroy() 
{
    Node* temp;
    for(Node* current = start; current; current = current->next, delete temp)
      temp = current;
    start = NULL;
    end = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. The only problem with the copy function though is that it does not "remake" the list as intended but instead adds to the current one in some way, at least that's what I got from testing it out. I have to admit that I'm still a beginner in C++. Well, at least I'm closer to solving this.

Comment: NP, you could observe the "adding" since you did not set start and end to NULL at the end of destroy().

Comment: Well, the problem now is that though I've corrected that mistake I still get strange results from the fibonacci function (I've added a for-loop). Instead of just giving me a large number when I let it calculate f.e. the 10th number it gives me a lot of nodes with only 1 digit in all of them. I think I might have made another mistake in the function, though I can't see this one either. (It's just a for loop with 1 addition and 2 copy's)